# New associated object in popup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

```
class Miniature < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :collections, dependent: :destroy
```

In a Miniature view I am trying to launch a popup form to create a new Collection associated with the current Miniature.

```
<i class="fa fa-check-square-o"></i>
<a href="#collection-popup" class="open-popup-link">
  Add to collection or wantlist</a>

<div id="collection-popup" class="white-popup mfp-hide">
    <%= render 'collections/pop_form' %>
</div>
```

The popup form starts with

```
<%= form_for(@collection, :html => { :class => "form-horizontal"} ) do |f| %>
            <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, :value => current_user.id %>
              <%= f.hidden_field :miniature_id, :value => @miniature_id %>
            <%= f.label :status, 'Got, Want or Had?', class: "control-label"  %>
```

So I get the error "First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty".

If I then define @collection in my Miniatures or Application controller as it is in my Collections controller:

```
  def set_collection
    @collection = Collection.new(@miniature)
    @miniature_id = params[:miniature_id]
    @miniature = Miniature.find(params[:miniature_id])
  end
```

then I get the error "Couldn't find Miniature without an ID".

How can I pass the @miniature to the partial?

Should I be able to do this with accepts_nested_attributes_for and without adding more controller logic? Rusty.

My miniatures controller

```
class MiniaturesController < ApplicationController
   before_action :contributor, only: [:new, :create, :edit, :update]
   before_action :admin_user,     only: :destroy

  def show
    @miniature = Miniature.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @miniature = Miniature.new 

    @all_scales = Scale.all
    @all_manufacturers = Manufacturer.all
    @all_sculptors = Sculptor.all

    @size = @miniature.sizes.build
    @production = @miniature.productions.build
    @sculpting = @miniature.sculptings.build
  end

  def create
    @miniature = Miniature.new(miniature_params)
    if params[:miniature][:"release_date(2i)"] == ''
      # no month is given, insert fake month and day
      params[:miniature][:"release_date(2i)"] = '1'
      params[:miniature][:"release_date(3i)"] = '1'
      mask = 4 # 100
    elsif params[:miniature][:"release_date(3i)"] == ''
      # no day is given, insert a fake day
      params[:miniature][:"release_date(3i)"] = '1'
      mask = 6 # 110
    else
      # full-date
      mask = 7 # 111
    end
    @miniature = Miniature.new(miniature_params.merge(date_mask: mask))


    if params[:scales][:id]
      ## Convert ["", "1","2","4","8"] to [1,2,4,8]
      params[:scales][:id] = params[:scales][:id].reject(&:empty?).map(&:to_i)
      params[:scales][:id].each do |scale|
        @miniature.sizes.build(:scale_id => scale)
      end
    end
    if params[:manufacturers][:id]
      ## Convert ["", "1","2","4","8"] to [1,2,4,8]
      params[:manufacturers][:id] = params[:manufacturers][:id].reject(&:empty?).map(&:to_i)
      params[:manufacturers][:id].each do |manufacturer|
        @miniature.productions.build(:manufacturer_id => manufacturer)
      end
    end
    if params[:sculptors][:id]
      ## Convert ["", "1","2","4","8"] to [1,2,4,8]
      params[:sculptors][:id] = params[:sculptors][:id].reject(&:empty?).map(&:to_i)
      params[:sculptors][:id].each do |sculptor|
        @miniature.sculptings.build(:sculptor_id => sculptor)
      end
    end

    if @miniature.save
      flash[:success] = "Miniature added. #{undo_link}"
      redirect_to @miniature
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def edit
    @miniature = Miniature.find(params[:id])
    @all_scales = Scale.all
    @all_manufacturers = Manufacturer.all
    @all_sculptors = Sculptor.all
    @size = @miniature.sizes.build
    @production = @miniature.productions.build
    @sculpting = @miniature.sculptings.build
    @production_versions = Version.where(:item_type => Production).where("object like ? or object_changes like ?", "%miniature_id: #{@miniature.id}%", "%miniature_id:
- 
- #{@miniature.id}%")
    @sculpting_versions = Version.where(:item_type => Sculpting).where("object like ? or object_changes like ?", "%miniature_id: #{@miniature.id}%", "%miniature_id:
- 
- #{@miniature.id}%")
  end

  def update
    @miniature = Miniature.find(params[:id])
     if params[:miniature][:"release_date(2i)"] == ''
      # no month is given, insert fake month and day
      params[:miniature][:"release_date(2i)"] = '1'
      params[:miniature][:"release_date(3i)"] = '1'
      mask = 4 # 100
    elsif params[:miniature][:"release_date(3i)"] == ''
      # no day is given, insert a fake day
      params[:miniature][:"release_date(3i)"] = '1'
      mask = 6 # 110
    else
      # full-date
      mask = 7 # 111
    end

    if params[:scales][:id]
      ## Convert ["", "1","2","4","8"] to [1,2,4,8]
      params[:scales][:id] = params[:scales][:id].reject(&:empty?).map(&:to_i) 
      ## Get the scale_id from sizes already present in database [1,2,5,6] 
      old_scales = @miniature.sizes.pluck(:scale_id)
      ## Find the new scales to be added [1,2,4,8] - [1,2,5,6] = [4,8]
      new_scales = params[:scales][:id] - old_scales 
      ## Find the old_scales to be deleted [1,2,5,6] - [1,2,4,8] = [5,6]
      old_scales = old_scales - params[:scales][:id] 
      ## Build new_scales [4,8]
      new_scales.each do |scale|
        @miniature.sizes.build(:scale_id => scale)
      end
      ## Delete old_scales [5,6]
      Size.where(:miniature_id => @miniature.id).destroy_all(:scale_id => old_scales)
    end
    if params[:manufacturers][:id]
      ## Convert ["", "1","2","4","8"] to [1,2,4,8]
      params[:manufacturers][:id] = params[:manufacturers][:id].reject(&:empty?).map(&:to_i) 
      ## Get the manufacturer_id from productions already present in database [1,2,5,6] 
      old_manufacturers = @miniature.productions.pluck(:manufacturer_id)
      ## Find the new manufacturers to be added [1,2,4,8] - [1,2,5,6] = [4,8]
      new_manufacturers = params[:manufacturers][:id] - old_manufacturers 
      ## Find the old_manufacturers to be deleted [1,2,5,6] - [1,2,4,8] = [5,6]
      old_manufacturers = old_manufacturers - params[:manufacturers][:id] 
      ## Build new_manufacturers [4,8]
      new_manufacturers.each do |manufacturer|
        @miniature.productions.build(:manufacturer_id => manufacturer)
      end
      ## Delete old_manufacturers [5,6]
      Production.where(:miniature_id => @miniature.id).destroy_all(:manufacturer_id => old_manufacturers)
    end
    if params[:sculptors][:id]
      ## Convert ["", "1","2","4","8"] to [1,2,4,8]
      params[:sculptors][:id] = params[:sculptors][:id].reject(&:empty?).map(&:to_i) 
      ## Get the sculptor_id from sculptings already present in database [1,2,5,6] 
      old_sculptors = @miniature.sculptings.pluck(:sculptor_id)
      ## Find the new sculptors to be added [1,2,4,8] - [1,2,5,6] = [4,8]
      new_sculptors = params[:sculptors][:id] - old_sculptors 
      ## Find the old_sculptors to be deleted [1,2,5,6] - [1,2,4,8] = [5,6]
      old_sculptors = old_sculptors - params[:sculptors][:id] 
      ## Build new_sculptors [4,8]
      new_sculptors.each do |sculptor|
        @miniature.sculptings.build(:sculptor_id => sculptor)
      end
      ## Delete old_sculptors [5,6]
      Sculpting.where(:miniature_id => @miniature.id).destroy_all(:sculptor_id => old_sculptors)
    end
    if @miniature.update_attributes(miniature_params.merge(date_mask: mask))
      flash[:success] = "Miniature updated. #{undo_link}"
      redirect_to @miniature
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def index
    @search = Miniature.search(params[:q])
    @search.sorts = 'name ASC' if @search.sorts.empty?
    @miniatures = @search.result.uniq.paginate(page: params[:page])
  end

  def destroy
    @miniature = Miniature.find(params[:id])
    @miniature.destroy
    flash[:success] = "Miniature destroyed. #{undo_link}"
    redirect_to miniatures_path
  end

private
    def miniature_params
      params.require(:miniature).permit(:name, :release_date, :date_mask, :material, :pcode, :notes, :quantity, :random, :set, :multipart, :comment, productions_attributes: [:id, :manufacturer_id, :miniature_id], sizes_attributes: [:id, :scale_id, :miniature_id], sculptings_attributes: [:id, :sculptor_id, :miniature_id], minilines_attributes: [:id, :line_id, :miniature_id])
    end

    def admin_user
      if current_user != nil
        redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user.admin?
      else
        redirect_to(root_url)
      end
    end

    def contributor
      redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user.contributor?
    end

    def undo_link
      view_context.link_to("undo", revert_version_path(@miniature.versions.last), :method => :post) if @miniature.versions.last
    end

    def signed_in_user
      unless signed_in?
        store_location
        redirect_to signin_url, notice: "Please sign in."
      end
  end
end
```

Comment: This line `@collection = Collection.new(@miniature)` is before you have defined @miniature, move it after `@miniature = Miniature.find(params[:miniature_id])`

Comment: It still says "Couldn't find Miniature without an ID" because nothing is being passed to the partial.

Comment: In which case you're not passing `miniature_id` in params, can you post your full controller code and how you get to it i.e. the link you click I'm assuming

Comment: the link you click is the above <a href="#collection-popup" class="open-popup-link"> which loads <%= render 'collections/pop_form' %> but I can't make any iteration of passing a param work in that render partial. Which controller would you like the full code of? The Collections controller or the Miniatures controller?

Comment: I mean the link that gets you to the page where the pop up link is, and can you edit your question adding in the full controller code.

Comment: The link to the Miniature show page is just <%= miniature.name, miniature %> from the index. Adding my entire miniature and collection controllers will be a lot of code. I'll edit them a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok if your link is just

```
<%= link_to miniature.name, miniature %>
```

Then it's not passing `miniature_id` but simply id, as you're on the show action of the miniatures controller.

So you need to change it like this:

```
@miniature_id = params[:id]
@miniature = Miniature.find(params[:id])
@collection = Collection.new(@miniature)
```

If you're always going to have `@miniature` defined I would get rid of `@miniature_id` and just use `@miniature.id`

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. Now I'm getting "undefined method `stringify_keys'" for the line beginning "@collection ="

Comment: Rails won't allow you to just pass in an object and have it be set in a `belongs_to` so make it `@collection = Colleciton.new(miniature: @miniature)`

Comment: YES! That works. Just have to delete the "@miniature = Miniature.find(params[:id])" line as well. Fantastic. Thank you. Do you want to edit the answer and then I'll tick it?

Comment: I'm now having the same problem with the index view. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24802303/pass-param-to-partial