# Pass param to partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails

**Update**

I'm beginning to think this isn't possible. If it was a link rather than a partial I could pass a param but because it's a partial I can't give my form the :id of individual miniatures from this index. Does that sound right? I may have to think of another way to do my popup?

I'm launching a form in a popup with this code:

```
    <a href="#collection-popup" class="open-popup-link">
              <i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>

    <div id="collection-popup" class="white-popup mfp-hide">
        <%= render 'collections/pop_form' %>
    </div>

<script>
$('.open-popup-link').magnificPopup({
  type:'inline',
  midClick: true // Allow opening popup on middle mouse click. Always set it to true if you don't provide alternative source in href.
});
</script>
```

The form it launches starts

```
<%= form_for(@collection, :html => { :class => "form-horizontal"} ) do |f| %>
            <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, :value => current_user.id %>
              <%= f.hidden_field :miniature_id, :value => @miniature_id %>
            <%= f.label :status, 'Got, Want or Had?', class: "control-label"  %>
```

It works fine from my @miniature show view but I'm now trying to get it to work on the index.

The controller has

```
def set_collection
    @miniature_id = params[:id]
    @collection = Collection.new(miniature: @miniature)
end
```

So it's expecting an [:id] param. In the index that id would be `miniature.id` but I can't find a way of passing `miniature.id` as :id in the params.

The Miniatures index action is as follows

```
def index
    @search = Miniature.search(params[:q])
    @search.sorts = 'name ASC' if @search.sorts.empty?
    @miniatures = @search.result.uniq.paginate(page: params[:page])
end
```

miniature.id DOES work on the index page alongside this because it's placed in the @miniatures partial that will_paginate uses. If I can show miniature.id then surely I can pass it to the form?

I've tried the following

```
<%= render 'collections/pop_form', { id: miniature } %>
<%= render 'collections/pop_form', { id: miniature.id } %>
<%= render 'collections/pop_form', { miniature.id :id } %>
<%= render 'collections/pop_form', { id: id } %>
```

But I can't get the right one.

Comment: it should be `<%= render 'collections/pop_form', { id: @miniature.id } %>`if you are getting @miniature object on that page then you can access the miniature id by using @miniature.id

Comment: It's an index with <%= render @miniatures %> so each @miniature is as miniature. So @miniature.id returns "undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass". I feel like {id: miniature.id} ought to work but it doesn't.

Comment: The index doesn't pass an id parameter, so params[:id] is nil.  You  need to find a miniature you want to use

Comment: I've edited to address that.

Answer (score 1):

Rendering a partial, does NOT call an associated controller action. So you need to define all the objects used within the page and the partials inserted into that page, via the action that matches the page.

So if the controller has the action:

```
def show
  @texts = ['foo','bar']
end
```

And the view has:

```
<h1><%= @texts.join(' ') %></h1>

<%= render 'some/partial' %>
```

Some partial can contain this:

```
<%= @texts.first %>
```

@texts defined in the controller action is available to both the host page and the partials.

The hash after the partial declarations allows you to pass in local attributes to the partials. It does NOT generate params that will be passed to the controller.

So you can do this in the view:

```
<%= render 'some/partial', locals: {something: texts.first}
```

And then in the partial:

```
<%= something %>
```

In both these examples the output will be:

```
<h1>foo bar</h1>
foo
```

That's just scraping the surface and I'd recommend you look at the Rails Guide: [Layouts and Rendering in Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials)

Comment: I realise it doesn't call the controller action. The content of the partial calls on the controller action. I probably should have given that. I will edit.

Comment: The form on submission, will return params[:collection][:miniture_id] as the value in @miniture_id.

Comment: But .... as both Alex P and I have stated - you should have a look at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials

Comment: Sorry. I meant to say that I have read through that a number of times. The problem I am having is, when I look at the logs, the form is passing "miniature_id"=>"". Always empty. Because it's an index there isn't a '@miniature' right? Only a list of miniatures. I need to take the miniature.id of each one and pass that to the form as '@miniature', right?

Comment: I get that partials are just bring code in, not a separate page but does that mean I need to use differently worded form rather than try and share the form partial with the show view?

Answer (score 0):

You should check out the [Rails guide on passing variables in to partial templates](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#passing-local-variables). In particular, you want to explicitly set it as a partial, and name your local variables hash. If your first view is being rendered by the `set_collection` controller action you posted, you'll have an `@miniature_id` variable available to you. Thus, your render call should be:

```
<%= render partial: 'collections/pop_form', locals: {id: @miniature_id} %>
```

Comment: My first view is not being rendered by the set_collection controller action. I may have made that confusing. I've edited my question.